# Spring MVC - как подтягивается конфигурация в Spring Context

Tags: spring, mvc

Изучаю Spring MVC и пытаюсь разобраться с инициализацией.
Есть класс инициализации:

```
public class AppInit extends 
AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

     @Override
     protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
     return new Class<?>[]{
             WebConfig.class
     };
}

 @Override
 protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
     return new Class<?>[]{
             WebConfig.class
     };
 }

 @Override
 protected String[] getServletMappings() {
     return new String[]{"/"};
 }
 }
```

Он подтягивает остальную конфигруацию WebConfig.class и т.п. Но кто вызвает сам класс инициализации AppInit. Нет нигде ссылки на него, никакого пути. Нигде. 
Подозреваю, что сканируются все файлы в проекте, но в этом классе инициализации нет аннотаций.

На просторах документации есть упоминание, что он подтягивается сервлет контенейром автоматически, но ничего более. Но почему именно он ?

Или при сканировании всех файлов идет поиск методов getRootConfigClasses, getServletConfigClasses и т.п. 
Верно ?

Comment: А вы не заметили что класс наследует `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`? Ищите в спецификации именно этот класс

Comment: заметил конечно. Но не пойму когда вызвается AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer и если это так, то он вызывает и свой дочерний ?